# How to fetch the next set of results from a paginated API?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm fetching data from an API that is paginated server-side. I have limited the number of results to 5 (rows=5). For the first set of data, a global variable `pageNumber` has been declared to 1, and `eventListeners` for the Previous/Next buttons have been added. Now I don't know how to get the next set of results. They can be fetched by changing the `pageNumber` to 2 but I don't know how to access the URL from const endpoint where I would change the `pageNumber` parameters to get previous and/or next results. Any idea how to do that?

```js
// First set of fetched data starts with page 1
let pageNumber = 1;

// 1. Define endpoint, fetch response and return data promise
const search = async (term) => {
    const key = 'aroplosuitin';

    const endpoint = `https://api.europeana.eu/record/v2/search.json`,
        query = `?wskey=${key}&query=${term}&start=${pageNumber}&rows=5&profile=rich'`;

    const response = await fetch(endpoint + query);

    // Check response status:
    if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Cannot fetch data. Response status is not 200.');
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
};

// 2. Call search and return data promise
const searchEuropeana = async (term) => {
    const data = await search(term);

    return data;
};

// 3. Grab the input and invoke callback to update the UI
const searchForm = document.querySelector('#search-form');

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // grab user input
    const userInput = searchForm.search.value.trim();
    // reset form on submit
    searchForm.reset();

    // For errors
    const errorOutput = document.querySelector('.error');

    // Invoke searchEuropeana
    searchEuropeana(userInput)
        .then((data) => {
            updateUI(data);
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('An error occured:', error),
                (errorOutput.innerText = 'Check your spelling or network.');
        });
});

// 4. Update the UI with HTML template
const updateUI = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
};

// 5. Previous / Next results
const previousBtn = document.querySelector('#previousBtn'),
    nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

previousBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (pageNumber > 1) {
        pageNumber--;
    } else {
        return;
    }
    console.log(pageNumber);
    searchEuropeana();
});

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pageNumber++;
    console.log(pageNumber);
    searchEuropeana();
});
```

```html
        <main id="main">
                <h2>(Be)Heading</h2>
                <br>
                <section id="search">
                    <form id="search-form">
                        <div class="form-group search-group">
                            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" required>

                            <button id="searchButton" class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </section>

                <br>

                <section id="output">
                    <!-- Error messages -->
                    <div class="error"></div>
                </section>        
                
                <button id="previousBtn" class="btn" type="submit">Previous</button>
                <button id="nextBtn" class="btn" type="submit">Next</button>
        </main>
```

Comment: your `pageNumber` seems like a global variable. So it should update from the `previousBtn` and `nextBtn` click handlers. You're calling `searchEuropeana` after `pageNumber` is incremented/decremented so it should be fine

Comment: Yes, it's global but the endpoint URL is not and I don't understand how to access that, i.e. nothing happens with just searchEuropeana() and incrementing pageNumber.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your API is getting called correctly. If you check the network tab in your developer console, you should see a new request with correct page number. The reason your `updateUI` function doesn't get called is because you don't have `searchEuropeana(searchForm.search.value.trim()).then( data => updateUI(data))` in either of your `previousBtn` and `nextBtn` click handlers

Comment: Yep, you're right. New network request does indeed exist, but it deviates from the search query because it doesn't continue the same query. This is the original: https://api.europeana.eu/record/v2/search.json?wskey=aroplosuitin&query=london&start=1&rows=20&profile=rich%27, 
and this is the next  one: https://api.europeana.eu/record/v2/search.json?wskey=aroplosuitin&query=undefined&start=2&rows=20&profile=rich%27.
Query becomes undefined. How could userInput stay as it was, i.e. continue where it left off?

Comment: yes, for the simple fix, just make your query variable global, just like pageNumber

Comment: There are better ways to do this, without polluting the global space, but this should unblock you for now

Comment: I don't know how to take the query out of the function when it depends on the passed argument (term) that is gonna be input by the user. Any suggestion?

Comment: Change your 1st line to `let pageNumber = 1, query = ''`;

Comment: and remove `,` from the end of the line `const endPoint` and replace it with a semicolon `';`

Comment: remove const endpoint = `https://api.europeana.eu/record/v2/search.json`, line and replace it with const endpoint = `https://api.europeana.eu/record/v2/search.json`;

Comment: So, you're saying to initialize empty query variable, okay. Const endpoint, okay. But what about query now, `?wskey=${key}&query=${term}&start=${pageNumber}&rows=5&profile=rich'`?

Comment: Yes, replace `${term}` with `${query}`

Comment: Or, better yet, put your 1st line as `let pageNumber = 1, term = ''`

Comment: Can you, please, write an answer as a solution so that we don't stretch it through the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// First set of fetched data starts with page 1
let pageNumber = 1;
let term = '';

// 1. Define endpoint, fetch response and return data promise
const search = async () => {
    const key = 'aroplosuitin';

    const endpoint = `https://api.europeana.eu/record/v2/search.json`,
        query = `?wskey=${key}&query=${term}&start=${pageNumber}&rows=5&profile=rich'`;

    const response = await fetch(endpoint + query);

    // Check response status:
    if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Cannot fetch data. Response status is not 200.');
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
};

// 2. Call search and return data promise
const searchEuropeana = async () => {
    const data = await search();

    return data;
};

// 3. Grab the input and invoke callback to update the UI
const searchForm = document.querySelector('#search-form');

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // grab user input
    term = searchForm.search.value.trim();
    // reset form on submit
    searchForm.reset();

    // For errors
    const errorOutput = document.querySelector('.error');

    // Invoke searchEuropeana
    searchEuropeana()
        .then((data) => {
            updateUI(data);
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('An error occured:', error),
                (errorOutput.innerText = 'Check your spelling or network.');
        });
});

// 4. Update the UI with HTML template
const updateUI = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
};

// 5. Previous / Next results
const previousBtn = document.querySelector('#previousBtn'),
    nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

previousBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (pageNumber > 1) {
        pageNumber--;
    } else {
        return;
    }
    console.log(pageNumber);
    searchEuropeana();
});

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pageNumber++;
    console.log(pageNumber);
    searchEuropeana();
});
```

EDIT:

Take a look at a more readable approach

```
// First set of fetched data starts with page 1

const searchFormEl = document.querySelector("#search-form");
const errorEl = document.querySelector(".query");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
const prevBtn = document.querySelector("#previousBtn");
const searchEl = document.querySelector("#search");
let pageNumber = 1;

const getApiUrl = () => {
  const key = "aroplosuitin";
  const endPoint = `https://api.europeana.eu/record/v2/search.json`;
  const query = `?wskey=${key}&query=${searchEl.value.trim()}&start=${pageNumber}&rows=5&profile=rich'`;
  return `${endPoint}${query}`;
};

// 1. Define endpoint, fetch response and return data promise
const search = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(getApiUrl());

  // Check response status:
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Cannot fetch data. Response status is not 200.");
  }

  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
};

// 2. Call search and return data promise
const searchEuropeana = async () => await search();

// 3. Grab the input and invoke callback to update the UI

searchFormEl.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Invoke searchEuropeana
  searchEuropeana()
    .then((data) => {
      updateUI(data);
      console.log(data);
      searchFormEl.reset();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("An error occured:", error);
      errorEl.innerText = "Check your spelling or network.";
    });
});

// 4. Update the UI with HTML template
const updateUI = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
};

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  pageNumber = pageNumber > 1 ? pageNumber - 1 : pageNumber;
  searchEuropeana().then(updateUI);
});

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  pageNumber++;
  searchEuropeana().then(updateUI);
});
```

Comment: No worries, take a look at updated answer

Comment: I get it. URL gets its own expression separate from the search function. Good idea!